# IOException al usar fileOutputStream para guardar un dibujo

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy realizando una app de reformas en el cual tengo un plano que aparece por popup y tengo que dibujar sobre el, necesito guardar el dibujo que hago con el plano de fondo de manera local. Pero cada vez que inicia el try  del fileOutputStream salta directamente al catch del IOException dandome el error de no tener acceso cuando en el manifest le tengo dados los permisos.

El error que me da es el siguiente:

> ```
> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/test.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
> W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
> W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
> ```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.reformaexpress">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Pop del plano**

```
public class PlanoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Path mPath = new Path();
    public static Paint paint_brush = new Paint();
    private Bitmap mBitmap;


    Button btnsave,btndelete;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_estado);
        DisplayMetrics medidas = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(medidas);
        int ancho = medidas.widthPixels;
        int alto = medidas.heightPixels;
        getWindow().setLayout(ancho=1000,alto=1750);

        paint_brush.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(ancho,alto, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);



        btnsave=findViewById(R.id.btn_guardar_estado);
        btndelete=findViewById(R.id.btn_borrar_estado);
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                asksave();
            }
        });
        btndelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                delete();
            }
        });
    }
    public void asksave(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Atención");
        builder.setMessage("¿Deseas guardar el estado actual del plano?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                save();


            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }
    public void delete(){
        pathList.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Borrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void save(){
        File sdDirectory = Environment.getStorageDirectory();
        File image = new File(sdDirectory, "/test.jpg");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);

            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            Log.e("TAG", "Entro en el try");
            finish();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("TAG", "Entro en el 1 catch");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "Entro en el 2 catch");

        }
    }}
```

**ViewPlano.class**

```
public class display extends View {

public static ArrayList<Path>pathList = new ArrayList<>();
private ViewGroup.LayoutParams params;




public display(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public display(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public void init(Context context){
    paint_brush.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint_brush.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint_brush.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint_brush.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint_brush.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint_brush.setStrokeWidth(4f);

    params=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


  }
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    for (int i=0;i<pathList.size();i++){
        canvas.drawPath(pathList.get(i),paint_brush);
        invalidate();
    }
}





@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mPath.moveTo(x,y);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            mPath.lineTo(x,y);
            pathList.add(mPath);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}}
```

La verdad es que agradecería cualquier ayuda. Si necesitáis algo mas del código decidlo y lo subo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para API 23+, debe solicitar los permisos de reed/write aún así los tengas en tu  **Manifest.xml**.

**AndroidManifest.xml** - tengo declaro los permisos de lectura y escritura, pero no funcionará si no solicito explícitamente al usuario que le permita a mi app leer/escribir en el storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Para obtener documentación oficial sobre cómo solicitar permisos para API 23+ consulte [API SDK Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

```
// Storage Permisos
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

/**
 * Comprueba si la aplicación tiene permiso para escribir en el device storage
 *
 * Si la aplicación no tiene permiso, se le pedirá al usuario que otorgue permisos
 *
 * @param activity
 */
public static void verificarStoragePermisos(Activity activity) {
    // Comprueba si tenemos permiso de escritura
    int iPermisos = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (iPermisos != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // No tenemos permiso hay que solicitárselas al usuario
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Este código donde pido permisos donde debo ponerlo?

Comment: Al Activity o Padre que invoca a tu pop up PlanoActivity justo antes de invocarlo, haz la llamada al método verificarStoragePermisos(getActivity()), pon el código en el padre o crea una clase de utilitarios y coloca el código del método estático dentro.

Comment: Aún habiendo implementado eso, me sigue dando el mismo error. He mirado incluso de manera manual los permisos de la app y los tiene concedidos, no se que es lo que pasa

Comment: Tienes tú código en github para darle una debug ?

Comment: Aquí lo tienes es una plantilla de un taller, pero la funcionalidad es la misma.https://github.com/ordorika-benat/TallerGestionApp

Comment: Cambia en el manifest el activity en el que se inicia la app para no tener que iniciar sesion ni nada

Comment: oka, recién lo veo, ya te hice un pull request para que lo tomes como **ejemplo** lee por favor la descripción del pull request.

Comment: Su ahora hago merge de tu codigo, el mio no se romperá no?

Comment: No que va, el cambio es mínimo, nos trasladaríamos a un chat, pero te falta 9 ptos de reputación. Espero el ejemplo aclare tus dudas, pero de hecho te traerá nuevas dudas.

Comment: Pues si la verdad, ahora sigo sin ser capaz de guardar la imagén, entra en el try pero me la guarda sin el fondo

Comment: De hecho me guarda una imagen completemente negra. he cambiado el color del trazo a rojo para ver si era solo el fondo y es en general

Comment: Me parece que aquí es el tema de la compresión, la imagen creo que se lee bien una vez guardada, deseas que te apoye en esta parte también ?

Comment: Por favor, si no es mucha molestia

Comment: Te deje el pull request, solo debes ajustar las dimensiones de tu imagen para que te quede bacan, hay otras mejores formas de hacer lo que deseas, pero para no hacer tanta modificación en tu código solo he "parchado" para que te guarde la imagen de fondo y lo que dibujas. (lo siento olvide avisarte que ya estaba), espero si puedes te sirvió todo le des unos puntos extra a la respuesta.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Ahora puedo seguir adelante, te estoy muy agradecido por ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

El `LogCat` indica en el mensaje permisos denegados:

> W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/test.jpg: open
> failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

esto es relacionado a que **el permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` que debe especificarse en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` y además debes requerir el permiso manualmente**.

```
            //Check permissions Android 6.0+
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                checkExternalStoragePermission();
            }
```

puedes usar este método, al aceptar el permiso tu aplicación funcionara sin problemas.

```
private void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {          
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } 
}
```

---

No es necesario declarar los permisos `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` y `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` , únicamente necesitas:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```